# Remove all urls in a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

How can I remove all urls within a string regardless of where they appear using Javascript?

For example, for the following tweet-

```
"...Ready For It?" (@BloodPop ® Remix) out now -  https://example.com/rsKdAQzd2q
```

I would like to get back

```
"...Ready For It?" (@BloodPop ® Remix) out now -
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove all urls from the string, you can use regex to identify all the urls that are there in the string and then use `String.prototype.replace` to replace all the urls with empty characters.

This is [John Grubber's Regex](https://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) which can be used to match all urls.

```js
/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/g
```

So to replace all the urls just run a replace with the above regex

```js
let originalString = '"...Ready For It?" (@BloodPop ® Remix) out now -  https://example.com/rsKdAQzd2q'
let newString = originalString.replace(/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/g,'')
console.log(newString)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your urls do not contain a literal whitespace, you could use a regex [`https?.*?(?= |$)`](https://regex101.com/r/LFUl85/1) to match from http with an optional s to the next whitespace or end of the string:

```js
var str = '...Ready For It?" (@BloodPop ® Remix) out now -  https://example.com/rsKdAQzd2q';
str = str.replace(/https?.*?(?= |$)/g, "");
console.log(str);
```

Or split on a whitespace and check if the parts start with "http" and if so remove them.

```js
var string = "...Ready For It?\" (@BloodPop ® Remix) out now -  https://example.com/rsKdAQzd2q";
string = string.split(" ");

for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  if (string[i].substring(0, 4) === "http") {
    string.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
console.log(string.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can split it by white space

```
var givenText = '...Ready For It?" https://example2.com/rsKdAQzd2q (@BloodPop ® Remix) out now -  https://example.com/rsKdAQzd2q'
var allWords = givenText.split(' ');
```

Than you can filter out non url words using your own implementation for checking URL, here we can check index of :// for simplicity

```
    var allNonUrls = allWords.filter(function(s){ return 
      s.indexOf('://')===-1 // you can call custom predicate here
  });
```

So you non URL string will be:

```
var outputText = allNonUrls.join(' ');
// "...Ready For It?" (@BloodPop ® Remix) out now - "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression replace on the string to do this, however, finding a good expression to match all URLs is awkward. However something like:

```
str = str.replace(regex, '');
```

The correct regex to use has been the subject of many StackOverflow questions, it depends on whether you need to match only http(s)://xxx.yyy.zzz or a more general pattern such as www.xxx.yyy.

See this question for regex patterns to use: [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeUrl(input) {
            let regex = /http[%\?#\[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:~_\.-:\/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789]*/; 
            let result = input.replace(regex, '');
            return result;
}

let result = removeUrl('abc http://helloWorld" sdfsewr');
```